# How to assign a public IP to a server behind a Mikrotik rb1200, without NAT?

Tags: router, nat, mikrotik

I have a fiber connection with 5 public ips.

The ips are like this:

200.195.169.xxx/29

The Internet Link is connected to ether2. One of the public ips is used to the LAN.
ether1,ether3,ether4,ether5 belongs to my lan, and have the following ips:
192.168.55.1/24

I have another computer running Apache, connected to ether6.
What I want to do, is to assign one of my publics ip to this server, without nat.

Hope you understand. What should I do?

thanks.

**Edit**

I need this, because I will install cpanel on the computer used as server. And cpanel won't run well behind NAT.

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic at Server Fault because they customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply, and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign the public IP to the server as a loopback IP (not associated with any interface)
2. Configure the router to route traffic to that public IP to the server's internal IP. (Just add one static route.)
3. Make sure the router is configured to pass the outbound traffic unmolested. (Don't assume all traffic from the internal network has an internal source IP. Or just add a rule to route traffic from the internal LAN with that particular source IP.)

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: the part of "Configure the router to route traffic to that public IP to the server's internal IP"  - Where I do this on mikrotik? ip > routes ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a single static route.

Comment: any idea about where i do this on mikrotik? thks

Answer (score 0):

From memory it goes something like this:

1. Plug your server into ether6.
2. Remove ether6 from bridge-local
3. Assign the public IP you want to reach the server at on the
   server.    With default route for the server being the mikrotik
   router public ip.

Done.